# Access javascript variable in memory using injection

Tags: javascript, browser, javascript-injection

Let's say I have a variable `db` in my client side code. If I do `window.db = db`, we can easily access it by doing injection or opening dev tools and typing `window.db`. But how can we use injection and get 
access to variable `db` if I don't assign it to `window` but it's still seating in the memory of my page?

According to what I've seen in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200790/how-easy-is-it-to-hack-javascript-in-a-browser), data downloaded into client side is highly vulnerable. Not to mention I have my `db` loaded in memory. So there must be a way of doing this.

My thought: What I'm missing here is simply a global reference to my `db` because I have not assigned it to the `window`. So how do we get that reference when we are using console and when we are doing injection.

Comment: If you are not referencing your downloaded data in your code, the garbage collector will gobble it up. If you use a local db variable within some sort of closure (like a function) it will be garbage collected once that function finishes. 

This means that to alter scoped variables you can open developer tools and set a breakpoint in the scope you wish to modify and once the script reaches that point you are able to do so.

Comment: @ProudOne I just did what I asked by setting up breakpoint. Thank you!